# Is there a way to add an active class onClick for an array of buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I map through the buttons array and get three buttons. What i want to achieve is to be able to identify which button is clicked and add an active class

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import style from "./years.module.scss";

const Years = props => {
 const [activeClass, setActiveClass] = useState(null);
 const buttons = ["year one", "year two", "year three"];



return (
 <div className={style.box}>
   {buttons.map((button, index) => {
       console.log(index,button)
     return (
       <button key={index} className={`${style.btn} ${style.active}`} >
         {button}
        </button>
     );
   })}
</div>
);
};

export default Years;
```

I use css modules to style the buttons

Comment: What have you tried to do in order to make them have an event? Can you show that in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just connect handler with each button - if clicked, the state is changed and stores the `index` of active button. If it's active - add class.

```
const changeActiveButton = (i) => () => {
   setActiveClass(i);
};

<button 
   onClick={changeActiveButton (index)}
   className={`${style.btn} ${index === activeClass ? style.active : ''}`}
>
```

Comment: I get an error:
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: @EirikVattøy Edited my answer